# Raw memory access Java/Python

Tags: java, pointers, reference

> **Memory-mapped hardware**
>
> On some computing architectures, pointers can be used to directly
>   manipulate memory or memory-mapped devices.
>
> Assigning addresses to pointers is an invaluable tool when programming
>   microcontrollers. Below is a simple example declaring a pointer of
>   type int and initialising it to a hexadecimal address in this example
>   the constant 0x7FFF:
>
> int *hardware_address = (int *)0x7FFF;
>
> In the mid 80s, using the BIOS to access the video capabilities of PCs
>   was slow. Applications that were display-intensive typically used to
>   access CGA video memory directly by casting the hexadecimal constant
>   0xB8000 to a pointer to an array of 80 unsigned 16-bit int values.
>   Each value consisted of an ASCII code in the low byte, and a colour in
>   the high byte. Thus, to put the letter 'A' at row 5, column 2 in
>   bright white on blue, one would write code like the following:

```
#define VID ((unsigned short (*)[80])0xB8000)

void foo() {
    VID[4][1] = 0x1F00 | 'A';
}
```

is such thing possible in Java/Python in the absence of pointers?

EDIT:

is such an acces possible:

```
char* m_ptr=(char*)0x603920;
printf("\nm_ptr: %c",*m_ptr);
```

?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do with this?

Comment: just reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm totally uncertain of the context and thus useful application of what you're trying to do, but here goes:

The [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jni/) should allow direct memory access within the process space. Similarly, [python can load c module](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) that would provide an access method.

Unless you've got a driver loaded by the system to do the interfacing, however, any hardware device memory will be out-of-bounds. Even then, the driver / kernel module must be the one to address non-application space memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an operating system with `/dev/mem`, you can create a `MappedByteBuffer` onto it and do this sort of thing.

Comment: The standard Java documentation on MappedByteBuffer, combined with the   the results of 'man mem' or 'man proc' (for /proc/PID/mem) will tell you what you want.